# Charting aggregated data to a given entry from another column

Tags: excel, charts, grouping

I have CSV imported with a column *time* (like 10:20) and some data columns (like *data1, data2, data3*) occurred at that time. The csv-data is several months long and I want to chart the aggregated value for each each minute for the data columns. Means the chart would have 1440 (24*60) data points with minutes aggregated.

```
Example:
10:20,  34,  12
10:21,  233, 15
10:22,  1,   3
...
10:20   100, 2
10:21,  2, 23
10:22   4, 12   
...
 
--> Expected result
10:20, 134, 14
10:21, 235, 38
10:22, 5, 15
...
```

What is the best way to achieve this? Thank You

Comment: You may try using Power Query here, will it possible to attach the workbook in the post, !

Comment: Actually I'm already using Power Query for every CSV I import

Comment: Alright, so you can do the aggregation there as well, i dont think there should be any issues, right